# Is there an AJAX / php library to create configurator-like page (multiple choices and dynamic preview)?

Tags: php, ajax, web-applications

I'd like to build a web page (backend is the usual LAMP stack) which should behave like some sort of configurator. The user will be presented multiple choices (radio button like in functionality, i.e. all choices are concurrently visible and the active one is highlighted), his selections will decide what further multiple choices will be presented on the page, and so on traversing some sort of decision tree.

In addition to that, the same page will contain some sort of output that will be constantly updated (with server-generated content) with every choice the user does.

Is there some library or other software (either on the php side or on the browser side) which will help me implementing this thing in whole or in part?

*[I just know about jQuery, which I'm in the process of studying and starting to use for the first time, and not much else on both front- and back- ends]*

Comment: You're looking for a dynamic form generation library. Several exist. None of them are perfect. But that is what you're wanting.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, at least I know what to look for! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's very similar to chain select, but change the select tag into radio tag. But you also want some extra output..

Try this tutorial first, change the select input to radio, and study some jQuery to find out how to get the extra output you want.

http://www.script-tutorials.com/creating-ajaxy-chained-selects-with-jquery/